# jenkins Docker agent: not working (/var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied)

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins node/slave where i have docker installed.

I can check that (the jenkins user is able to a spin docker)

```
[stg-jenkins-slv-1] jenkins:~$ docker run --rm -it node16_16_0_custom_build:latest  /bin/bash
node@8508f61f549c:/home/simha/app$
```

also

```
uid=1009(jenkins) gid=1011(jenkins) groups=1011(jenkins),0(root),27(sudo),115(docker)
```

and my jenkins file is

```
stage('Build reacjts project') {
    agent { 
        docker { 
            label 'jenkins-slv-1'
            image 'node16_16_0_custom_build:latest'}
    }
    steps {
        sh '''
            node --version
            npm install
            npm run build
        '''
    }
}
```

I using the lable which corresponds to the jenkins slave/node where the docker is working fine.

but still i am getting

```
+ docker inspect -f . node16_16_0_custom_build:latest

Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/containers/node16_16_0_custom_build:latest/json": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

How to konw the above thing is being access by which user. i am assuming it being accessed by jenkins user on that jenkins slave as lable.

I also tried to restart jenkins server. Because this is not the main jenkins server, its just a node/slave

```
[stg-jenkins-slv-1] jenkins:~$ sudo service jenkins restart
Failed to restart jenkins.service: Unit jenkins.service not found.
```

Not able to undestand the issue.

Atlease is there any way to know which user is being used by docker agent to start the docker image, then i can add that user to the docker group

Comment: `sudo service jenkins restart`  this can be run on where jenkins server is running. But mine is a node/slave. I added to the docker group

Comment: do i have to restart the server for this